# How to shift a block of code left/right by one space in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I can use alt-up and alt-down to move a line or block up or down, but I can't find a command to increase or decrease indent by one space.

I *can* indent/outdent by multiples of tabSize, but that's not quite general enough for me, and I don't really want to set tabSize=1.

(In Vim I made handy shortcuts to move a line or lines up/down/left/right with ctrl-k/j/h/l - it was probably the most useful bit of Vimscript I ever wrote.)

Comment: Why do you want to break the consistency of indents? When someone else opens your code in a different editor it'll be all over the shop?!

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.indent-one-space

Comment: My use case tends to be indenting blocks of parameters to functions, which are often aligned to the open param on the preceding line. Even if I'm working with tab-like indentation, I like the symmetry of up/down/left/right rather than one thing for up/down and another for left/right.

Comment: @Alex I think you have the answer, happy to accept it!

Comment: VS has no built-in toolbar....strange ideed!!!

Comment: Hi cdyson37.  VS Code has added the feature.  May I recommend you change the accepted answer?

Comment: Which answer do you think is now correct?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

There was a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22637) for that in vscode repo. But it was marked as `extension-candidate` and closed. So, here is the extension: [Indent One space](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.indent-one-space)

> Unlike the answer below that tells you to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> this extension indents code by **ONE** whtespace ‍♂️.

[image]

Comment: Amazing!!! I had gave up finding it, it saved my year. Just an observation: use [space] to right, and [shift]+[space] to left/reverse.

Comment: That theme looks beautiful, too bad I never seen it on my shell.

Comment: To move text from left to right, select the code then press TAB.

Comment: if you have the Vim extension installed then you have to delete the Vim shortcut to make this shortcut work, alternatively you can disable the extension as well.

Answer (score 110):

***UPDATE***

While these methods work, newer versions of VS Code uses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> shortcut to indent a block of code once, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to remove indentation.

This method detects the indentation in a file and indents accordingly.You can change the size of indentation by clicking on the Select Indentation setting in the bottom right of VS Code (looks something like "Spaces: 2"), selecting "Indent using Spaces" from the drop-down menu and then selecting by how many spaces you would like to indent.

Comment: But it doesn't do 1 space if file indent is 4 spaces.  OP wants 1 space in a 4-space context.

Comment: This is useful information, however I wanted to indent/de-indent code by exactly one space irrespective of the prevailing indentation convention of the file (for example, to make groups of arguments line up in a multi-line function call).

Comment: TAB characters are into the text.  You can make those TAB characters display as a single character but that strategy will blow up if the text is show in a different editor stetting with normal settings.

Comment: It will work if "Indent Using Spaces" is set in Settings, althouth that van be overriden if there are already TABS in the files. "Indent Using Spaces"  was suggested below in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53463975/4376643

Answer (score 92):

No need to use any tool for that

1. Set Tab Spaces to 1.
2. Select whole block of code and then press **Shift + Tab**

Shift + Tab = Shift text **right to left**

Comment: It's worth to mention that you need to use Tab to move right and Shift + Tab to the left

Comment: There's no need to set Tab Spaces to 1. Tab to move right, Shift + Tab to move left

Answer (score 13):

Recent versions of VSCode (*e.g., Version 1.29 at the time of posting this answer*) allow you to change the Tab/Space size to `1` (or any number between `1` and `8`). You may change the Tab/Space size from the *bottom-right* corner as shown in the below image:

[image: Change Tab/Space size]

Click on `Spaces:4`. Then, select **Indent Using Spaces** or **Indent Using Tabs** and choose the size **1**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice and clean temp indent solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at **File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts** (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

Search for `cursorColumnSelectDown` or `cursorColumnSelectUp` which will give you the relevent keyboard shortcut. For me it is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down/Up Arrow</kbd>

Comment: I think this is for selecting columns rather than shifting them?

Comment: @cdyson37 Yes, this select the columns. Then Space or Tab will shift the columns to the right. Backspace or Shift+Tab will shift the columns to the left.

Answer (score 5):

In MacOS, a simple way is to use Sublime settings and bindings.

Navigate to VS Code.

> Click on **Help** -> **Welcome**

On the top right, you can find ***Customise*** section and in that click on **Sublime**.

Bingo. Done.

Reload VS Code and you are free to use `Command` + `[` and `Command` + `]`

Answer (score 4):

Another work-around (my installed VS Code v1.53.0)

1. Select block of code
2. Go to "**Selection**" > "**Column Selection mode**"
3. Hit backspace to shift

Answer (score 3):

```
Current Version 1.38.1
```

I had a problem with intending. The default <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> is set to 4 and I wanted it to be 2. Installed "Indent 4-to-2" but it changed the entire file and not the selected text.

I changed the tab spacing in settings and it was simple.

Go to `Settings` -> `Text Editor` -> `Tab Size`