# How to shift multiple lines of code to the left at once in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autohotkey

[image]

I tried to shift the lines using `ALT+CLICK` but it erased the `t` from the word `Height` and also break the indentation inside the `loop`.

[image]

What the correct way to shift multiple lines at once including lines inside collapsed brackets?

Comment: you could move a selection up and down, mark the codeblock to move - hold ```alt``` and use cursor up or down, if this is enough for your scenario

Comment: I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: If you just want shift everything to the left, use shift tab.

Comment: @kraego shift tab did it, is possible to change this behavior to default? I mean, instead `select all lines > shift+tab`, just `select all lines > backpspace`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shift a block of code left/right by one space in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903209/how-to-shift-a-block-of-code-left-right-by-one-space-in-vscode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select Code Block and press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>
2. Select Code Block <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> (for left shift one indent), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> (for right shift one indent)
3. Change to `column selection`, select all rows (cursor a position of code to shift) + <kbd>backspace</kbd>

Comment: It does not work when on lines collapsed, you know why?

Comment: Yes you're right, the collapsed lines are not shifted, when using method 3. Hard to tell if it's a feature or a bug.